# Working with large array on disk

Tags: c#

I need to work with a large 2-dimensional array of doubles, with more than 100 million cells. The matrix first needs to be filled and then manipulated by taking either one row or one column. The matrix can be bigger than 1 terabyte in size, and will not find in memory.

How can the array be stored efficiently? The main operation is fast saving it from memory row by row (double[100k] each) and fast reading to the memory of one row or one column.

Comment: 1m * 100k = 100km, that is for double around 100GB! I suspect you are working with graphics, but then you cannot just simply copy that whole thing to the memory and expect to work with it. You need to do it batch by batch, you and need a fast indexing way of storing and locating cells.

Comment: Ghasan, thanks for you reply. I'm not working with graphics, rather with Monte-Carlo simulation with the need to reuse extensively intermediate calculations. The fast way of storing and indexing cells is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Memory Mapped Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files). You are essentially still working with an array, but allowing the kernel to choose what parts to load into memory. You could also possibly use [Fixed size buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers) to read whole sections of the memory mapped files.